# Add cocoa pod to iOS independent Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I would like to create a framework that is archived and distributed on its own. The problem I'm having is that I would like this library to have cocoa pod dependency libraries compiled into it. Is this possible?

It seems to work. But when I embed the framework in a sample app and invoke code of the embedded dependency I get an error: `dyld: Library not loaded:... Reason: image not found`

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MySDK' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'ALBNoSQLDB', '~> 4.2'
end
```

Do I have to run an archive script to embed the dependent pods? Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you distributing your framework?  If you are distributing it as a pod itself, then you can specify its dependencies and pod install will fix it for you. If you are distributing in some other way then you need to include the built frameworks in. Carthage may be a better choice than cocoa pods for your dependencies

Comment: You're right. I forgot that I can include the dependencies in the .podspec.